# Trouble recognizing my file directory when using file.path()

Tags: r, windows, path

I am trying to set a file path for my documents and for some reason no matter what I do, I get an error.

```
path_to_file <- file.path("C","Users","Surface_1453","Desktop","HI_Hawk_Nesters","HI_Ei_location_and_dive_data")

tbl_locs <- readr::read_csv(path_to_file)
```

My first line setting the file path runs fine however I change it but when I run the second line I get this error:

> Error:
> 'C/Users/Surface_1453/Desktop/HI_Hawk_Nesters/HI_Ei_location_and_dive_data'
> does not exist in current working directory
> ('C:/Users/Surface_1453/Documents').

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Your file path requires the extension.  Add .csv to the file.path.  Also (and I'm not sure about this), but notice the file path in the error message, which has a "C/" whereas on Windows I believe you need a "C:".

Comment: I have tried it lots of ways including adding the CSV at the end and it still didn't work. However, I did not know about the C: so I will try that next! Thanks!

Comment: Still didn't work with this: 
path_to_file <- file.path("C:","Users","Surface_1453","Desktop","HI_Hawk_Nesters","HI_Ei_location_and_dive_data", "Location_Metadata_HI_Hawk_Nesters.csv")

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an absolute path to the file. Namely,

```
tbl_locs <- readr::read_csv(file = "C:/Users/Surface_1453/Desktop/HI_Hawk_Nesters/HI_Ei_location_and_dive_data.csv")
```

As @Dany point it out, the "file.path" wouldn't help to add `:` and your file extension `.csv`. Also, I would just use an absolute path or relative path to `file` parameter in `read_csv`.

1. **Absolute path** means the complete file path in your computer. In your case, it is `C:/Users/Surface_1453/Desktop/HI_Hawk_Nesters/HI_Ei_location_and_dive_data.csv`.
2. **Relative path** means the file path relative to your current working directory (`wd`), it is `../Desktop/HI_Hawk_Nesters/HI_Ei_location_and_dive_data.csv` as your `wd` is `C:/Users/Surface_1453/Documents`.

Both paths should work with your `read_csv` function.

Comment: I tried that and am now getting this error: Error: 'read_csv' is not an exported object from 'namespace:reader'

Comment: @AlisonMeeth There is a typo in the answer. It should be `readr::read_csv`.